# Как удалить @ из всех слов кроме email-адресов Regex

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Подскажите пожалуйста, как удалить `@` во всех словах в строке?

`@` не должна удаляться если это email:

```
text @user @user2 @user3, user@mail.ru text@ text user2@mail.ru ,!@user5, вы@user6,
```

Comment: Ну всего-то и делов, что сформулировать критерий для определения, где e-mail, а где нет... что (с учётом отсутствия готового решения столь стандартной на первый взгляд задачи) будет весьма непросто.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/OuciDC/1 ну вот тут регэксп написал, который вроде выбирает то что нужно, а как менять я не знаю.

Comment: А какой должен быть результат? "!@user5" - это адрес эл. почты или нет?